# changing dates to ages if the date is in format yearmonthdate in r

Tags: r, code-formatting

I am trying to change birthdate(s) into ages, using age_calc eeptools. The problem I'm running into is the format of the birthdate, which is written as yearmonthday with no breaks, for example, 20170724 Is there a way for me to alter a very large data set to a format that will work with the conversion?

Comment: `as.Date(as.character(20170724), "%Y%m%d")` should do it.

Comment: Or `lubridate::ymd("20170724")`